# Problem migration from SharePoint 2013 to 2016 with different farm account

Tags: migration

The source SharePoint 2013 farm and SharePoint 2016 target farm are created with different accounts.

The command Mount-SPContentDatabase runs without errors. In the Administration Center in the "Upgrade and Migration" section, the status of upgrade is successful.

But when you try to go to the web application address, it asks for a login-password three times, and then just shows a blank browser window. No content, no menu - nothing.

Advise how to make content and menus available on the new SharePoint 2016 farm.

A SharePoint 2016 farm account has been added to administrators and site collection owners.

Answer (score 0):

Has you application working correctly before migration? The issue you describe is usually caused by something different.

Your symptoms are pointing that you probably haven't set the SuperReader/SuperUser accounts or there is loop back check happening on that app. (if you google there are plenty of resources to be found how to address either of this issues)

Comment: Application working correctly before migration.

Comment: Have you reviewed the SR|SU set up and loopback check is disabled on this app?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right - loop back check happening

Comment: :) that was my gut feeling, please remember to mark as answer.